# Doeas analytics have 3 months limitation to search engine optimization screen

Tags: google-analytics, report, search-engine

Doeas anybody know that Google Analytics would have changed search engine optimization reports?

I remember that I have seen there long time reports, but after this summer it semmes like it only shows us past 3 months of data. It changes from day to day, older data disapers after day. and only 3 months shows up there.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Search Engine Optimization reports in Google Analytics are populated with data from Google Webmaster Tools (GWT).  You can only view 90 days (3 months) of historical data in GWT, which explains this behavior.  More info here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35252

Comment: This hasent been alway like this?   I clearly remeber seing that data on analytics longer perios than 3 months. On webmaster tools it has been always that 3 months. After We activated this on analytics it has been on analytics reports, with alla history after activation day.